# How to make notes of pdf files having around 500 pages?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing, ghostscript

I am using Ms windows and i am looking for a software that would enable me to make notes of pdf files. 
For pdf files, i use foxit reader and in my phd, i have to make notes of multiple papers. 
Right now, I am using onenote software of ms windows.

I wanted to know, if there is any better way to make notes of pdf files. This is being asked because in research papers having 30-40 pages, one-note works fine. But in large sized pdf files, it is very difficult to use onenote.

Is there some offline pdf editor(free), which would enable me to make notes in the pdf file itself and would allow me to edit the pdf file like a word file.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This question is off topic here, asking for product / service / learning material recommendation. Please read what's [on-topic here](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: So sorry. Will take care from next time on wards.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).